# object HTMLDivElement to string

Tags: javascript

How can one convert "object HTMLDivElement" to a string?

```
   let z = document.querySelector(".global_all_sessions");
   console.log(z) // No string`
```

Tried: `z = String(z)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: By searching the web and finding [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML). And in your code, of course, first verifying that `z` is something, because you may have typoed your query selector.

Comment: What is the exact input and what is the exact desired result?

Comment: The outerHTML attribute helped, thanks!